# Is it possible to change the color of grid lines in a chart and can we add dots at the data points in line chart in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to change the background gridline color of the line chart & can we dot at the data points of the line chart?
[image: Line chart]

Answer (score 1):

> Can you add markers (or dots) to the line chart?

Yes, but the X axis must be of type "categorical".
navigate to "Shapes" > "Show Marker" (on/off)

> Can you change the background grid line color?

Yes you can.

Expand "Y Axis" > navigate at the bottom until you find "Gridlines" (on/off) > here you have all the gridline settings

[image: background grid line settings]